# Using an svg file as the backgound for an angular app

Tags: angular, svg

I would like to use an svg file as the background for an angular app so that it scales along the rest when resized.
If I load it with:

```
<span><ng-include src="'resources/svg/caricaFornoWB.svg'" /></ng-include></span>
```

the svg is shown above the rest of the app. How may I show it in the background (possibly linking its objects to my own) instead?

Comment: use the SVG as a css background-image perhaps.

Comment: How do I do it? Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<img src="resources/svg/caricaFornoWB.svg" />
```

Comment: Nope, sorry, if I do so a broken image appears in that place, while if I show it in a sperate pan it correctly shows.

Comment: Perhaps issue with relative path try to use 

./resources/svg/caricaFornoWB.svg

or 

../resources/svg/caricaFornoWB.svg

or 

../../resources/svg/caricaFornoWB.svg

It depends on you folder structure

Comment: Yes, I tried using ./resources/svg/caricaFornoWB.svg to the same effect. As I said clicking the image it shows fine so the addressing should be fine.